# Set a namespace variable inside a namespace function

Tags: tcl

I have a package which uses some variables in lots of its functions. I put it in the namespace eval but then this sets the variable as soon as the package is imported, which I don't want, because its value depends on some things that I set later in my main.tcl.

```
namespace eval test {

    set variable val
}
```

Therefore, I want something as follows:

```
test::set_test_globals {} {
    set test::variable val
    }
```

But tcl doesn't like this one bit. I tried using upvar but it said the namespace doesn't exist.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Also, I took the liberty to edit your question's title: you're talking about namespace variables and namespace functions/commands, not package variables/functions as such. A package typically uses namespaces, but packages and namespaces are distinct concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with something like this:

```
namespace eval test {}

proc test::set_test_globals {} {
    variable variable val
}
```

If you use

```
proc test::set_test_globals_a {} {
    set test::variable a
}
```

`variable` will be created relative to the `test` namespace, i.e. as `::test::test::variable`, provided the `::test::test` namespace exists.

```
proc test::set_test_globals_b {} {
    set ::test::variable b
}
```

Here, using a qualified (absolute) namespace means that regardless of which namespace `set_test_globals_b` is in, the variable will be created in the `::test` namespace.

But there is a dedicated command, `variable`, which declares or creates variables in the current namespace without any further namespace specification.

```
proc test::set_test_globals_c {} {
    variable variable c
}
```

Since the command belongs to the `::test` namespace (assuming in all cases here that the `proc` calls are made in the global namespace and not inside any `namespace eval` scripts), the `variable` command ensures that the variable `variable` is created in the same namespace.

Note that you can also invoke the `variable` command with only the variable name as argument, in which case the variable is declared but does not yet exist.

```
proc test::set_test_globals_d {} {
    variable variable
    # variable does not exist here
    set variable d
    # variable now exists as ::test::variable
}
```

If `variable variable` had not been invoked in the last example, `set variable d` would have created as a local variable instead.

One common idiom is to use one-argument `variable` invocations inside a `namespace eval` to document that the namespace contains those variables:

```
namespace eval test {
    variable variable
    # variable does not exist yet
}

proc test::set_test_globals_d {} {
    variable variable
    # variable still does not exist here
    set variable d
    # ::test::variable now exists with the value d
}
```

Note that you still need to invoke `variable variable` again within each command that will use the namespace variable. The first command to assign a namespace variable a value creates it for the whole namespace and all commands that use it.

The name `variable` is a valid variable name even though there is a `variable` command, but it's probably less confusing to use another name for the variable.

For completeness, there is a `namespace upvar` command that creates links between local variables and namespace variables in much the same manner as `upvar` can do (i.e. `namespace upvar $ns a b` is almost, but not quite, the same as `upvar 0 ${ns}::a b`).

Documentation: [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm), [variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)

Comment: I know this is really old, but the use of a variable named 'variable' is very confusing because of the keyword `variable`.

Comment: @RussSchultz: Tcl doesn't have keywords. The string `variable` is only special if it is the first token in a command, in which case the corresponding command is called. I agree that using the string `variable` as a variable name in production code isn't best practice, but it's good enough for an example.